# HybridUrlCodingStrategy not compatible with google?

Tags: seo, wicket, friendly-url

We use `MixedParamHybridUrlCodingStrategy` in our Wicket application in order to have pretty url parsed by google. Url pattern :

```
http://host/domain-objecs/{id}/a-long-title-for-my-object
```

The page has some ajax stateful components.

When someone opens one of theses pages he is automatically redirected on :

```
http://host/domain-objecs/id/a-long-title-for-my-object.0
```

This is a problem for google which indicates crawling error due to the redirect.

Have you any ideas of how to resolve this problem? Not redirecting when the user-agent is a robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by making my page stateless.

I used the framework jolira http://code.google.com/p/jolira-tools/wiki/stateless to replace my links and a statelessForm in place of a classical form.